# Getting two results using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a friend list using mysql and php. My problem is that only one result is showing up, even though there are two friends for the user i am testing with. my code look as follows:

```
  <?php 

    if (isset($_POST['tag']) && !empty($_POST['tag'])) {
        $tag = $_POST['tag'];
        require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
        $db = new DB_Functions();
        $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);
        if($tag == 'friend_id_tag') {
            $uuid = $_POST['uuid'];
            if($db->userExists($uuid)) {
                $data = $db->getFriendList($uuid);
                if($data != false) {
                    $response["success"] = 1;   
                    $response["friend"] = $data["name"];
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }else {
                    echo "No existing user";
                }
            } else {
                echo "No existing user";
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

and the mysql query

```
    <?php

    class DB_Functions {
        private $db;
        //put your code here
        // constructor
        function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
        }
    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

        }
    function getFriendList($uuid) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM Account WHERE unique_id IN(SELECT friend_id FROM FriendList WHERE player_id = '$uuid' AND is_friends = 1)");
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function userExists($uuid) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE unique_id = '$uuid'");
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user existed
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            return false;
        }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: please improve your code. i don't understood with this code

Answer (score 1):

You should run while loop in function

```
function getFriendList($uuid) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM Account WHERE unique_id IN(SELECT friend_id FROM FriendList WHERE player_id = '$uuid' AND is_friends = 1)");
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $d = array();
            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $d[] = $data;
            }
            return $d;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try var_dump to check what response is coming

Answer (score 0):

Your getFriendList returns an array `$data = $db->getFriendList($uuid);`

but this part is not looped

`if($data != false) {
      $response["success"] = 1;

      $response["friend"] = $data["name"];
      echo json_encode($response);
}else {`

So that would just set $response['friend'] to the first user only.

UPDATE: added loop

`if($data != false) {
      $response["success"] = 1;
      for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
          $response["friend"][$i] = $data[$i]["name"];
      }
      echo json_encode($response);
}else {`

Comment: How would I loop it though?

Comment: I have added a loop to my answer

Comment: it kinda work, but now it only echos first letter in first friends name and second name is null

Comment: What is returned if you print the $data
`$data = $db->getFriendList($uuid);
      print_r($data);
      if($data != false) {`

Comment: Array ( [0] => 5358fb10e60140.50838520 [player_id] => 5358fb10e60140.50838520 [1] => 535e491d4be879.20073109 [friend_id] => 535e491d4be879.20073109 [2] => 1 [is_friends] => 1 )

Comment: THat was wrong hangon, Array ( [0] => Johan [name] => Johan ) {"tag":"friend_id_tag","success":1,"error":0,"friend":"Johan"}